# Emacs not loading function on start-up

Tags: org-mode, init-file

I put the following in my .init file:

```
(defun ndk/org-refile-candidates ()
  (directory-files  "/home/rob/Dokumente/todo/" t ".*\\.org$"))

(add-to-list 'org-refile-targets '(ndk/org-refile-candidates :maxlevel . 3))
```

It does work when evaluating manually with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd>, but not when I restart Emacs.

I get the error:

> Symbol's value as variable is void: org-refile-targets
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
> cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
> the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.

Why isn't it setting the value of the variable like when I do it manually? Does it get overwritten by some default somehow? Can somebody point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because no variable `org-refile-targets` has yet been defined when that code in your init file is being evaluated.

(Obviously you've loaded the relevant library by the time you attempt this manually.)

It looks like `org-refile` is the library which defines this, so you can either forcibly load that before using the variable:

```el
(require 'org-refile)
(add-to-list 'org-refile-targets '(ndk/org-refile-candidates :maxlevel . 3))
```

But I can see that's going to load much of `org` in turn, which is a bit of a performance hit at start-up, so I suggest this instead:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'org-refile
  (add-to-list 'org-refile-targets '(ndk/org-refile-candidates :maxlevel . 3)))
```

Comment: thank you, sir phils! that was very helpful :)